# Are microwave ovens dangerous to digital cameras?

Tags: equipment-protection

Okay, I'm not talking about putting a camera *inside* a microwave oven! ;)

But does storing a digital camera near a microwave oven (one that is used regularly) damage it in any way?  I'm thinking perhaps any degradation of the image sensor.

Comment: How near is "near"? Bear in mind that microwave ovens also get hot and vent steam etc. depending on what you are cooking. (?)

Comment: See the video [How a Microwave Oven Works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kp33ZprO0Ck) by engineerguy.

Answer (score 26):

No, there is no danger. Any EM fields *outside* the microwave are very weak. There is no danger or risk.

Microwaves are like visible light waves, except bigger (the "micro" is in comparison to other radio waves). Both are non-ionizing radiation; they don't have the energy to displace electrons in atoms. And, just like visible light, microwave radiation follows the inverse-square law and drops off dramatically as you move away.

Microwaves use exactly the same radio waves used for WiFi, except with higher power and greater concentration. However, the box of the microwave keeps that confined. In the US, [Federal regulations](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/granule/CFR-2012-title21-vol8/CFR-2012-title21-vol8-sec1030-10) limit the amount of leaked microwaves for the lifetime of the device (that is, not just when brand new) to 5 milliwatts of microwave radiation per square centimeter measured 5 centimeters from the box. For comparison, the FCC limits WiFi routers to 1000 mW (or, you know, one watt). And, you shouldn't worry about either.

Comment: Wow!  Great answer!  Thank you!  So, if I understand correctly, at 0cm, a WiFi router can be 200 times stronger than a microwave oven at 5cm.  Right?

Comment: _"Any EM fields outside the microwave are very weak"_ - That [seems to be more true in theory than in practice](https://superuser.com/questions/637594/why-does-my-microwave-kill-the-wi-fi/637838#637838).  I do agree though that it's unlikely to affect a digital camera.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft "weak" by "could damage your camera" standards are not the same as "weak" by "can be detected by a radio receiver" standards. Not by many orders of magnitude. On the right frequencies, I can hear a transmitter with the same power as a microwave from the opposite side of the globe on my radio receiver, but I'm not concerned in the slightest about damage to my camera, or my eyes.

Comment: wrt ionising vs non-ionising radiation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation#/media/File:EM-spectrum.svg

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Next question, then, is can wifi damage digital cameras...

Comment: @DrEval If that's the question, the answer is "no".

Comment: Well, that means it can disrupt the operation of a camera when it is operated remotely via WiFI ...

Answer (score 4):

Let's try physics. And math.

By regulation, the maximum power density outside the microwave is 5mW per cm<sup>2</sup> at 5 centimeters away.

For comparison, a typical cell phone has a transmit power of about 500mW. Spread over a sphere of radius 5cm, that's a power density of 500mW / (4*pi*5cm<sup>2</sup>) = 1.6mW per cm<sup>2</sup>.

1.6 and 5 are roughly the same, within an order of magnitude. Your camera is probably farther than 5cm from the microwave oven, and you probably aren't afraid to set a camera closer than 5cm from a phone. Come to think of it, there's probably a camera *inside* the phone.

So unless there's some reason the electromagnetic radiation from a microwave is more harmful than a cell phone (I can't think of one) there's no reason to be concerned.

Comment: Note that the limit for new microwaves is 1mW/cm²